# Creating a channel that only the message.author can see python

Tags: python, discord

As said in the title, I want to make it so upon command, it creates a channel that only the author of the message can view and type in. I know how to create a channel.

```
await client.create_channel(message.server, "Channel", type = discord.ChannelType.text)
```

But I don't know how to set up the permissions.

Answer (score 1):

```py
    import discord
    everyone = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=False)
    mine = discord.PermissionOverwrite(read_messages=True)
    await client.create_channel(message.server, 'secret', (message.server.default_role, everyone), (message.server.me, mine))
```

See the "secret text channel" in the [docs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Client.create_channel) ; TextChannel will be used by default